# WordPress disallows changing page to a specific permalink

Tags: permalinks

A site I am supporting is using WordPress 4.7.5 and is configured to use month-and-name permalinks.

There is a page titled "Upcoming Events" which is a child of a page named "Connect" whose permalink (less the hostname) is `/connect/events-2`.

Attempting to change the permalink via the Edit Page admin page to `/connect/events` immediately sets it back to `/connect/events-2`.

Attempting to set it to `/connect/events-3` does work.

Attempting to set it to `/connect/events` when it is `/connect/events-3` changes it to `/connect/events-2`.

### Some things I have checked:

- There is not another page whose title or permalink is events.  There are no pages in the trash.
- Navigating to `/connect/events` does a 301 redirect to `/connect/events-2`.  So that seems to confirm that it is not due to a another page using the name.
- I exported the `wp_posts` table (via the hosting tools, not via WordPress).  There are other entries whose `post_title` is "Events" but they are old revisions of the page of interest (`post_type` is `revision`, `post_status` is `inherit`, `post_parent` is the page's `ID`).  There are no entries whose `post_name` is "`events`".

What else could cause WordPress to disallow "events" in the permalink?